# Test Django create_user of an AbstractUser without username

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to test the creation of an user in Django. But my user model is not the standard one (email is the username).

### **models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager as AbstractUserManager

class UserManager(AbstractUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    username = None
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

### **tests.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CustomUserTests(TestCase):
    def test_create_user(self):
        user = get_user_model()
        utilisateur = user.create_user(
            email='test@tester.com',
            password='testpass123',
        )
        self.assertEqual(utilisateur.email, 'test@tester.com')
```

> Error
> line 10, in test_create_user
> utilisateur = user.create_user( AttributeError: type object 'CustomUser' has no attribute 'create_user'

Something is missing but I don't know how to test well this...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CustomUser' has no attribute 'create_user'

`create_user` is not present on the `CustomUser` model and that's what the error is saying. The method is present on the `UserManager` and the manager is defined on the user model as `objects = UserManager()`.

So to access the method, you need to use `user.objects.create_user`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a beginner please forgive me for this.

Comment: @mevaereR glad that I was able to help. On a side note, you don't have ask forgiveness for this and at least not from me :). If at all, ask it from the code ;-).